# What does the law say about a person who orders a hit on themselves?

Tags: murder, suicide

Imagine this hypothetical situation.

Anonymously, e.g. via the Internet, you find a hitman and pay him to murder yourself.

Imagine the hitman failed, you survived and the police somehow learned about this whole situation.

What could you potentially be charged with? Will you be imprisoned?

I'm curious about all the countries of the world.

Comment: Related: [What crime is hiring someone to kill you and then killing the hitman?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/62103/35069)

Comment: The linked question contains a significant additional element, and so is not a duplicate IMO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What crime is hiring someone to kill you and then killing the hitman?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/62103/what-crime-is-hiring-someone-to-kill-you-and-then-killing-the-hitman)

Answer (score 3):

## [germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

Someone inciting someone to commit a crime is to be punished as if he committed the crime himself in addition to the actual perpetrator. [§26 StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__26.html)

Murder is punished by lifelong imprisonment. [§211 StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__211.html)

The attempt of a crime is punishable by the same punishment as the execution of it, or with a reduced sentence. [§23 StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__23.html)

You can agree to your body being harmed by someone (like in a martial arts tourney), but that doesn't make it legal if the harming of the body is against "Gute Sitten" (~morals) [§228 StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__228.html) This includes (attempted) murder.

### Conclusion

Hiring a hitman is punished by lifelong imprisonment for **inciting** someone to **attempt**/commit the crime of **murder**. Failure in murdering someone makes it an attempt. If your incitement of the (attempted) murder can be proven, it doesn't matter if the hitman never tried to execute the murder or grossly failed - Or even if you failed to hire the hitman: The attempt of inciting someone to murder you is punished as if you had murdered someone.